# my BroadcastReceiver can't receiver the phone state change

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

the receiver is defined in manifest.xml :

```
  <receiver android:name=".PhoneStateBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

and receiver is very simple :

```
    public class PhoneStateBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
          ...
           public void onReceive(){
                 Log.d("receiver","called");
           }
    }
```

I replace the intent-filter to a custom filter defined by myself , and send a broadcast using "sendbroadcast()"  ,it works well, but can't receiver the phone state broadcast ,  where is the problem?
thanks

ps:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
```

this is my permission ,and test is on two emulator android 6.0 .

Comment: and  I  also have added the read phone state permission :

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how to do that:

```
public class PhoneStatReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{        

        private static final String TAG = "PhoneStatReceiver"; 

        private static boolean incomingFlag = false;

        private static String incoming_number = null;

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)){                        

           incomingFlag = false;

           String phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);        

            Log.i(TAG, "call OUT:"+phoneNumber);                        

           }
           else{                        
              TelephonyManager tm =(TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Service.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);                                                  

              switch (tm.getCallState()) {

                        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:

                               incomingFlag = true;

                                incoming_number = intent.getStringExtra("incoming_number");

                                Log.i(TAG, "RINGING :"+ incoming_number);

                                break;

                        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:                                

                                if(incomingFlag){

                                        Log.i(TAG, "incoming ACCEPT :"+ incoming_number);

                                }

                                break;
                        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:                                

                                if(incomingFlag){

                                        Log.i(TAG, "incoming IDLE");                                

                                }

                                break;

                        } 

                }

        }

}
```

Register it in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<receiver android:name=".filter.PhoneStatReceiver">  

            <intent-filter>

                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>           

                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />

            </intent-filter>

</receiver>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: i use your code  but ,still can't get the onReceiver()  to be called , it seems  the system not send phone state change broadcast   ,i guess @Archit Goel